# Change event action based on other event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a generally accepted method to change the action of a JavaScript event?

The following seems clean, but doesn't work as the first event is bound to `#link` when the page is rendered, and nothing changes when the class changes.  Does it sound like I understand this correctly?

```
$('#change-to-option-1').click(function(){$('#link').attr('class','option-1');});
$('#change-to-option-2').click(function(){$('#link').attr('class','option-2');});

$('.option-1').click(function(){alert('option 1');});
$('.option-2').click(function(){alert('option 2');});

<a href="#" id="change-to-option-1">Option 1</a>
<a href="#" id="change-to-option-2">Option 2</a>

<a href="#" id="link" class="option-1">Click Me</a>
```

Or should I have one event, and put logic in it based on the element's class (or maybe `data()`) instead as shown?

```
$('#link').click(function(){
  if( ('#link').attr('class')=='option-1') {alert('option 1');}
  else{alert('option 2');}
});
```

Or is there a generally more accepted approach?

Comment: Since the class is acting as a flag of sorts, the second approach seems fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make an event trigger for an element after changing its class/any identity that you used to bind the event initially. Then you have to go for [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on("click", ".option-1", function(){ alert('option 1'); });
```

You can expect the code to be optimized if you use any closest static parent of `.option-1` instead of `document`

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend and prefer hardcoding anything. So here's a solution which would take care of what you are trying to do.

```
$('#change-to-option-1,#change-to-option-2').click(function(){
   $('#link').attr('class',this.id.split('-')[2] + '-' + this.id.split('-')[3]);
});

 $('#link').on('click',$(this).attr("class"), function()
 {
      alert($(this).attr("class"));
 });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/39fvpstq/

If you plan to introduce more anchor links with a similar id structure :

```
$('[id^=change-to-option-]').click(function(){
   $('#link').attr('class',this.id.split('-')[2] + '-' + this.id.split('-')[3]);
});

 $('#link').on('click',$(this).attr("class"), function()
 {
      alert($(this).attr("class"));
 });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/39fvpstq/1/

If you wish to put everything in one event block :

```
$('#change-to-option-1,#change-to-option-2').click(function(){
   $('#link').unbind('click');
   $('#link').attr('class',this.id.split('-')[2] + '-' + this.id.split('-')[3]).on('click',$(this).attr("class"), function()
   { alert($(this).attr("class"));
   });
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/39fvpstq/2/